# Change level of heading in "List of tables" and "List of figures"

Tags: table-of-contents, lists, tocbibind

How can I change level of heading in "List of tables" and "List of figures"?

I am using the usepackage tocbibind to get them on the table of contents, and \renewcommand{} to rename them.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What do you mean by “change level of heading”?

Comment: Example, from  \chapter{} to \section{} @egreg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `\tableofcontents` and `\listtablename` to wathever you want to change, then change `\section` to what level of the heading you want.

Example 1

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\listoftables{%
\subsection{\listtablename{}}%
\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listtablename}%
     {\MakeUppercase\listtablename}%
\@starttoc{toc}%
}
\makeatother
```

Example 2

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\listoffigures{%
\subsection{\listfigurename{}}%
\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
     {\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
\@starttoc{toc}%
}
\makeatother
```

[Found an answer here.](http://texblog.org/2014/03/25/table-of-contents-list-of-figures-and-tables-as-sections-in-a-report/)

Comment: Where's the connection to tocbibind here then?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I am not sure if I understand what you mean.

Comment: Well, you wrote about `tocbibind` usage -- now you are using a totally different solution whereas the `tocbindind` manual shows example(s) how to change the level of the relevant `list of ...` ... why the hard way?

Comment: @Niklas Did you try this? I did for `\listoffigures` and got two subsection numbered entries in the ToC like "0.0.1 List of Figures", one indented in normal font with a page number and the other non-indented in a large bold font with no page number.

Comment: @PeterWilson I removed the numbering with "\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}" for TOC, LOF, and LOT.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I didn't know about that, but I cant see a way to use that to change the heading to subsection.

Comment: @Niklas How/where did you put your `\setcounter...`? It does not appear in your answer which as it stands is no good. [GOM]

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand your question all you need to do is put

```
\usepackage[section]{tocbibind}
```

in your preamble.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. I cant get this to work, could you possibly create an short example? Would prefere the use of subsection instead of section.

Comment: @Niklas Your statement "I can't get this to work" is of no help. Did you put `\usepackage[section]{tocbibind}` in your preamble? Show an MWE. In your comment to @egreg you wanted to go from `\chapter{}` to `\section{}`. Going to `\subsection{}` is a different issue which I will leave you to deal with.

Comment: I am sorry for being wage, I can get it to work the way you suggested but not the way I want. I looked over the manual for the usepackage and come to the conclusion that it only works with "section". But as my question stated I want to be able to change the level of the heading to whatever (subsubsection, subsection, etc).

Comment: @Niklas Your question was about "change level of heading"  and when asked what this meant you said "Example from `\chapter{}` to `\section{}`.  That was what I gave a solution to. I answered your original question but now you have asked a different one.